# How to find out the algebraic integer in some fields.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

As shown in the title: How to find all the algebraic integer in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$

Comment: Have you shown/seen/read that the sum and product of two algebraic integers is again algebraic?

Comment: Yes, I know it!

Comment: Well then, what is your definition of $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}]$?

Comment: In this case you can do it explicitly. Pick an element of your field and compute its minimal polynomial over $\mathbf Q$. See what the element must look like in order for the minimal polynomial to have integral coefficients.

Comment: Maybe he meant $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ rather than $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-1}]$.

Comment: @Robert Soupe What's the difference?

Comment: @RobertSoupe adjoining an algebraic element to a field always yields a field

Comment: It's a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, which is generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: In general, for these quadratics, the algebraic integers include at least numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt d$ where $a$ and $b$ are usual integers. It maybe also include other numbers depending on whether $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. If no one else writes up a more thorough answer, I'll do so tonight.

Comment: @Alex We like to get hung up on notation on this website.

Comment: I think no different, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ has the same elements as a set.

Comment: @ Alex Macedo Thanks for your hint!

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but I think we've failed to identify the correct original.